# Cell class is missing

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

Error:

```
Cell class Audit.AuditCell is missing. Cake\View\Exception\MissingCellException
```

Plugin files:

```
plugins/Audit/src/Template/Cell/Audit/model.ctp
plugins/Audit/src/View/Cell/AuditCell.php
```

In, `src/Template/Servers/view.ctp`:

```
echo $this->cell('Audit.Audit::model', [strtolower($this->request->controller), $this->request->pass[0]]);
```

In, `config/bootstrap.php`:

```
Plugin::load('Audit', ['bootstrap' => true, 'routes' => true]);
```

Using `CakePHP 3.3.16`.

**Edit #1**

Snapshot of my IDE:

[image]

**Edit #2**

Relevant parts of my composer.json

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.5.9",
    "cakephp/cakephp": "3.3.*",
    "mobiledetect/mobiledetectlib": "2.*",
    "cakephp/migrations": "~1.0",
    "cakephp/plugin-installer": "*",
    "adayth/cakephp-cipher-behavior": "^1.0"
},
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "src",
        "Audit\\": "./plugins/Audit/src"
    }
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\Test\\": "tests",
        "Cake\\Test\\": "./vendor/cakephp/cakephp/tests",
        "Audit\\Test\\": "./plugins/Audit/tests"
    }
```

Comment: Maybe there's a typo in the classname, maybe the file isn't accessible (permissions), maybe the file doesn't exist in the environment, maybe the plugin isn't included in your autoloader, ...

Comment: @ndm autoloader? bootstrap.php or composer.json ? I'm loading the plugin inside bootstrap.php ATM.

Comment: `composer.json`, respectively the autoloader generated from the information therein. **https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/plugins.html#autoloading-plugin-classes**

Comment: Added bootstrap.json parts...

Comment: In your file AuditCell.php, do you have this namespace: **namespace Audit\View\Cell;**

Comment: @benfarhat, that was it! If you put in an answer, I'll mark it as such. I just remembered, I initially created the cell in the app and moved it in the plugin, explaining the mismatching namespace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the proper `namespace Audit\View\Cell` to my file.